# Make a block in absolute position to be the width of its text content

Tags: html, css

I know that we can make a `div`'s width equal to its content in different ways:

Applying one of the following:

```
- display:inline-block
- float:left
- position:absolute
```

But for some reason I am not being able to force my div to grow according to it's text content, it just adjusts to the shortest width possible as soon as space is present, or in other words the biggest word in the div will determine the element's witdh.

I really want everything to stay in one line.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cBL62/1/

Thanks for the help, this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap` to `.zone_title`:

```
.zone_title {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1cd9af;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 100%;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cBL62/4/)**

Comment: Wow! Awsome, first time I hear of that, is it compatible in all browsers?

Comment: All the way back to IE 5.5.

Answer (score 2):

`white-space: nowrap;` for div will do trick for you.